# String to hex encode problem .by encode() module but failed

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Incorrect result on encoding

I tried to convert a string to a byte in hex format by encode() but failed. 
Below is my code, I expected \xFF will become \xFF , but finally the result is \xc3.

May i know why?

Input: `x ="\x00\x00\xFF\x00\xFF\x00"`

Input: `x.encode()`

Output: `b'\x00\x00\xc3\xbf\x00\xc3\xbf\x00'`

Comment: What do you want as output? A `bytes` object?

Comment: The output you're getting are the bytes you end up with if you encode that 6 character string as UTF-8. It looks alright to me - what did you expect? Note that if you do `y = x.encode()` and then `y.decode()` you get `x` back exactly as before.

Answer (score 2):

The default encoding for string.encode() is UTF-8.  UTF-8 encodes characters with numeric decimal codes 0-127 as their numeric values.  It encodes values greater than 127 as two or more bytes depending on the character being encoded.

The UTF-8 encoding for 0 is 0.  The UTF-8 encoding for '\xFF'(255) is '\xc3\xbf'.

So if you replace your input with the UTF-8 encoding for each of the 6 bytes in that input, you get your output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the equivalent bytes object, as opposed to the encoded string, you can get it like this:

```
>>> x ="\x00\x00\xFF\x00\xFF\x00"
>>> bytes(x, 'latin-1')
b'\x00\x00\xff\x00\xff\x00'
```